# Data value not showing in v-select in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

```
<v-form :model='management'>
 <v-flex xs3 sm2 md3>
  <div class="form-group>
   <v-select
    :items="days"
    item-text='text'
    item-value='text'
    placeholder="MM"
    single-line
    attach
    v-model="week.day"
    >
   </v-select>
  </div>
 </v-flex>
 <v-flex xs12 sm4>
  <div class="form-group">
   <v-text-field
    v-model='week.daily_shift'
    name="postal_code"
    >
   </v-text-field>
  </div>
 </v-flex>
 <v-btn @click.prevent='submitManagement'> Save</v-btn>
</v-form>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        days: [
          {text: '01'},
          {text: '02'},
          {text: '03'},
          {text: '04'},
          {text: '05'},
          {text: '06'},
          {text: '07'}
        ],
        week: {
          day: '',
          daily_shift: ''
        }
    }
    created: function() {
      this.fetchWeek();
    }
 }
</script>
```

The issue I am facing here that the value I have a value of **week.day** in my database to be equal to **4** but it doesn't show that value in the  tag. I checked using the debugger I am receiving the value of day as well as daily_shift value on created. The value of daily_shift shows in the  tag. Have I implemented item-value, item-text the correct way? Am I doing something wrong. Help me find my problem.

Comment: perhaps because 4 !== 04?

Comment: suggest you use `text: '01', value: 1` etc, then you don't even need to specify `item-text` or `item-value` since you'd be using the defaults

Comment: also, `attach` ... shouldn't that have some sort of value (as per documentation)

Comment: @JaromandaX it worked. Awesome. Thankyou.